# Rabl issues in rendering has_many associations with limit properties

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rabl

I have a model which has two relationships.

model.rb

```
has_many :items
has_many :top_items, :class_name => "Item", :limit => 3
```

So when rendering json in page like index, I only want to get top_items. But Rabl doesn't seem to know this. It just pops out every items I have instead of 3. Below is my rabl code

```
child :top_items do |top_item|
    attributes :id, :name
end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
If you eager load an association with a specified :limit option, it will be 
ignored, returning all the associated objects
```

So it's impossible to limit the child size from the has_many association.